# How to use minikube on Windows 10 home edition?

Tags: windows, kubernetes

I use mingw on Windows. It likes Linux. I downloaded `minikube` and `kubectl` Windows edition and set alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias minikube=/c/Users/username/minikube/minikube.exe
alias kubectl=/c/Users/username/kubectl/kubectl.exe
```

If I run `minikube` or `kubectl`, they works well.

But I want to start minikube:

```
$ minikube start
```

Then got error:

```
========================================
kubectl could not be found on your path.  kubectl is a requirement for using minikube
To install kubectl, please do the following:

download kubectl from:
https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.6.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe
Add kubectl to your system PATH

To disable this message, run the following:

minikube config set WantKubectlDownloadMsg false
========================================
Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
Starting VM...
E0509 17:37:04.195865    4880 start.go:116] Error starting host: Error loading existing host. Please try running [minikube delete], then run [minikube start] again.: Error getting migrated host: unexpected end of JSON input.

 Retrying.
E0509 17:37:04.199770    4880 start.go:122] Error starting host:  Error loading existing host. Please try running [minikube delete], then run [minikube start] again.: Error getting migrated host: unexpected end of JSON input
```

Why can't it realize the host?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.minikube
```

Then run start again:

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
```